# Is it called "composition" if we are using primitive data types?

Tags: java, terminology, class-design, composition, data-types

The following is an example of "composition":

```
public class Car
{
    Engine engine;  // Engine is a class
}
```

But is it still called "composition" if we are using primitive data types? for example:

```
public class Car
{
    int x;  // int is a primitive data type
}
```

Comment: This might be specific to the author using the term composition - not all authors will use it in exactly the same way. But why does it matter what it's called? This seems like an English language question, not a software engineering question.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  More precisely, this is called [***object composition***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition): you compose a more complex object which access its components using their known interfaces (i.e. the operations defined for primitive data types).
In a Java context, there's a difference between primitive data types, which have value semantic, and class types, which have reference semantic, but in both cases, it is still object composition.

Be aware however that *composition* may also refer to ***composite aggregation*** (i.e. what UML calls composition). In a Java context, authors usually use the term in conjunction with reference semantic that enables polymorphism (such as in [*composition over inheritance*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)). A primitive data type does not meet the requirements of this more specific meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Note that composition as a software design term is used almost exclusively in an OOP context, to set it apart from inheritance. The word just means "collect things to make a bigger something". In an OOP context however it stresses a particular approach to class design: combine several objects in a container object opposed to adding functionality through sub-classing.

So while you could refer to any grouping of things as composition, you will typically not see the term used to describe a bunch of fields in a data record or a bunch of private members with primitive types in a class.

Also note that people can get worked up about this. Some will argue that composition will beat inheritance anytime, others will tell you these people are clueless.

Just saying.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason why Java even has primitives is performance. If objects would be equally fast during processing and require equally little memory, everything would have been an object, even `int`.

Ruby and Smalltalk, for example, only know objects. In these languages really everything is an object, even a simple integer value. This means they will never be as fast as a language with primitives, yet fast enough for common tasks.

C, on the other hand, only knows primitives, as even structures are just aggregates of primitives, yet they are treated like primitives themselves (they are passed by value). C also knows generic memory and typed pointers but that isn't the same as objects and the only content you can place into memory are primitives (pointers are just indirect references to primitives stored in heap memory).

The term composition describes a technique of building new entities out of existing entities (usually building more complex entities out of simple ones), instead of just implementing an interface from scratch or inheriting implementation (and possibly interfaces; think of JavaScript, which only knows implementation, not interfaces) of existing entities. Nowhere is demanded that these "entities" must be objects, though. Why wouldn't it be composition, just because the designers of a language decided that some things are not objects? If tomorrow Java makes `int` also a Class, yet the syntax of the language would stay the same (which would require a lot of magic in the compiler but is possible), would you even notice they are not primitives any longer?